# Is adding new tables more performant than extending existing tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Where I work we've had some discussions about how we should be structuring our database. There seem to be two schools of thought: half of us think that it's better, in both principle and performance, to add new tables as a means of extending 'things' in our database. For example, we have a table called 'Company'. When we want to add a new field to this table, we'd add a foreign key in and link off to a new table called 'CompanyField' which contains the actual data.

The other half of us prefer to just add a new column to the existing table, so long as it satisfies 3NF/4NF and the data is actually related etc.

My question is: are there performance gains to be made from separating out (large or small) tables into smaller ones. Some people have mentioned paging as a reason to split the tables up, but I don't know enough to comment.

(If it's relevant we're using MS-SQL).

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, performance is impacted if you split tables, or join tables, or change column types, or use partitioning. But *how* it is impacted and whether that matters is not something that admits an easy answer, so I'm voting to close this as too broad. In *general*, you should let the design be leading -- just because you didn't think of column X when you created the table doesn't mean it's not logically part of the table had you been aware of it from the start. That alone justifies simply extending the table.

Comment: Well consider what would happen if you added 10 new properties. Suddenly would you really want 10 joins to get one set of information across multiple 1:1 tables instead of a single table? Adding new columns like this seems like a really bad idea. I am surprised half of any team would think that is good.

Comment: It really depends on what kind of new columns you need. Lets take the example 'Company'. You would want to add 2 new attributes: 'IsRepresentatedInPanama' and 'IsJointStock'. Let's say for the first flag/attribute you only have 5% of the Companies with the flag 1. For the second flag its evenly spread. I would add the 'IsJointStock' as column and the other attribute added as an individual table 'CompanyRepresentatedInPanama' having only references to the few Companies that meet the criteria. Other than that, having a table with many attributes and values for other tables is not really useful.